# Why is there a build.gradle and a build.sbt in play framework?

Tags: scala, gradle, playframework, sbt

I'm starting to develop a web app with scala. What I don't understand is why we have a `build.gradle` file and a `build.sbt` file. There are dependencies defined in both files.

Which one should I use in what case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The files are equivalent, and that is why they both declare (almost) the same dependencies.

So you can use Gradle **or** sbt, but you won't need to use both. If you want to use Gradle, just remove `build.sbt`. If you want to use sbt, just remove `build.gradle`. They are both present in samples and seeds so that users can choose and see how to configure Gradle/sbt for that kind of project.

Comment: Please change "remove" to "ignore" (or better "also update"); what if you pick `sbt` for your scala project today, and gradle for your groovy project tomorrow. Shame the java project is still on maven; but someday...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I don't get your comment about "shame the java project is still on maven". Which Java project? This question is specific about Play templates/samples I think.